# django:two forms but only one form is saving

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Can anyone help me with this. What is the problem with this code because only one form is saved, that is form, but bform is not saved. Where did I go wrong??

views.py

```
def customerView(request, **kwargs):
    this_customer = customer.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = customerForm(request.POST, instance=this_customer)
        bform = buildingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and bform.is_valid():
            form.save()
            bform.save()
    else:
        form = customerForm(instance=this_customer)
        bform = buildingForm()
    return render_to_response('customer.html',{'form':form, 'bform':bform,},
                                context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class customerForm(ModelForm):
    F_NAME = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'34'}))
    L_NAME = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'34'}))  
    EMAIL  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'19'}))  
    ADD    = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'34'}))
    class Meta:
        model = customer

class buildingForm(ModelForm):
    CUSTOMER     = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'}))
    B_FLOORSPACE = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'4'}))
    B_YEAR       = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'4'})) 
    class Meta:
        model = building
        widgets = {'B_USE'       : RadioSelectNotNull(),
                   'B_TYPE'      : RadioSelectNotNull(),
                  }
```

Edited to add template-customer.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="customer">Save</button>  
  {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.id }} 

 ...more code...
<table> 
  <tr><td><div>First Name</div>{{ form.F_NAME }}</td></tr>     
  <tr><td><div>Last Name</div>{{ form.L_NAME }}</td></tr>
</table>

   ...more code....
<table> 
  <tr><td><div>Build Use</div></td><td>{{ bform.B_USE }}</td>
      <td><div>Build Space</div></td><td>{{ bform.B_FLOORSPACE }}</td>
      </tr>

 ...more code... 
</form>
```

There is no error saying that there is a mistake in the coding.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you post the portion of the template where you are rendering the forms?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `fields` line in the `Meta` class in the `buildingForm`, and specifying the customer/floorspace/year widgets in the `widgets` option along the use/type, instead of in the field constructor?

Comment: May be you need to user a [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix) for the two forms. You need to add it both while rendering the empty form, and while building a bound form from POST data.

Comment: Hi @PauloBu thks. I have added the template.

Comment: Hi @Mariano thks. Yes I have done that but no luck...still giving me the same problem.

Comment: Hi @akotian thks. I did also try that make it in two forms and use prefix but can't make it right. I can't make it function..Can you show me how it will look like then. thks a lot.

Comment: Well, what i see a little weird is the `<button type="submit" name="customer">Save</button>` line. I assume you use it for saving the form because I don't see any other `submit` elsewhere. Try to switch that line with this one: `<input type="submit" value="Save">` and see if it works. If not, notify to go on further.

Comment: @noobes, You can add prefix like so 
while rendering empty form:
`form = customerForm(instance=this_customer, prefix='customer')`
and `bform = buildingForm(prefix='building')`

while using POST data:
`form = customerForm(....,prefix='customer')`
and `bform = buildingForm(prefix='building')`

Also have you tried printing any form errors like so?
`bform.errors` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) and checking if data is bound to the form `bform.is_bound`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_bound)

Comment: Also `print request.POST` to check if it has the building data

Comment: @akotian I don't think there are errors to print. His validation code is `form.is_valid() and bform.is_valid()`. If there would've been errors then that `if` statement would've failed and none of the forms would've been saved, which is not the case.

Comment: @PauloBu I agree with you, was just suggesting some debugging steps :)

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're showing the two forms in separate form-elements in your template. The problem with this approach is that you can actually only submit one form at a time. Luckily, Django provides Formsets as a solution to this.

The appropriate docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: No need for formsets, just wrap the two Django forms in a single HTML <form> element.

Comment: You're right, I was a bit quick on the draw on this one. Formsets aren't the correct solution here.

Comment: Hi thks @DanielRoseman and j.koch my forms are wrap in a single html form but why it is still not saving. is there any wrong in the coding in views.py???it didn't give me any error though...